# @FindBy WebElements are not being initialised in a PageFactory/Page Object framework

Tags: java, selenium, pageobjects

Updated Code:

```
public class FlightBookingTest extends PageBase{

@Test(priority = 1)
@Parameters({"from", "to"})
public void searchForAPackage(String from, String to) throws InterruptedException {

    customerHomePage().selectDepartureAirport(from);
    customerHomePage().selectDestinationAirport(to);
    customerHomePage().selectStartDate();
    customerHomePage().submitSearchRequest();

    assertThat(searchResultsPage().checkPageTitle(), equalTo("Flight Results"));
}
```

Page Object:

```
public class CustomerHomePage extends PageBase {

@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = ".//* [@id='container']/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/h3")
public WebElement searchResults;  
//loads more locators

public CustomerHomePage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}

public void visit(String url){
    driver.get(baseURL);
}

public void selectDepartureAirport(String departureAirport) {
    click(whereFromDropdown);
    selectOption(departureAirport);
}

public void selectDestinationAirport(String destination) {
    click(destinationLocator);
    type(destination, destinationLocator);
    selectOption("(" + destination + ")");
}

public void selectFromDate() {
    type("15/07/2016", dateFromField);
}

public void submitSearchRequest() {
    click(submitSearchButton);
    waitForIsDisplayed(searchResults, 120);
}

public void selectStartDate() {
    click(dateFromField);
    click(nextMonthSelector);
    click(dayOfMonth);
}
```

PageBase:

```
public class PageBase extends  TestBase {

public CustomerHomePage customerHomePage()
{
    return PageFactory.initElements(driver, CustomerHomePage.class);
}
```

Test Base:

```
public class TestBase implements Config {

public WebDriver driver;
//a bunch of methods to handle Driver instantiation and kill

//a bunch of Webdriver utility methods including:
public void click(WebElement element) {
    waitForIsDisplayed(element, 120);
    element.click();
}
 public Boolean waitForIsDisplayed(WebElement element, Integer... timeout) {
    try {
        waitFor(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element),
                (timeout.length > 0 ? timeout[0] : null));
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException exception) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private void waitFor(ExpectedCondition<WebElement> condition, Integer timeout) {
    timeout = timeout != null ? timeout : 5;
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
    wait.until(condition); //java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException HERE...Caused by NoSuchElementException
}
```

Looks like framework is not respecting the wait for expected conditions - visibility of Element.  I suspect something to do with the implementation of 'visibilityOf(element)' and the way the @FindBy initialises the elements

Stack trace of exception:

```
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.findElement(Unknown Source)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.isDisplayed(Unknown Source)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.elementIfVisible(ExpectedConditions.java:302)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$100(ExpectedConditions.java:41)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$10.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:288)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$10.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:285)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:238)
at com.multicom.fabrix.framework.TestBase.waitFor(TestBase.java:152)
at com.multicom.fabrix.framework.TestBase.waitForIsDisplayed(TestBase.java:141)
at com.multicom.fabrix.pageobjects.CustomerHomePage.waitForResults(CustomerHomePage.java:75)
at com.multicom.fabrix.regressiontests.FlightBookingTest.searchForAPackage(FlightBookingTest.java:23)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:74)
at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:121)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.mycompany.mymodule.webdriver.WebDriverInvoker.invokeNormally(WebDriverInvoker.java:47)
at com.mycompany.mymodule.webdriver.WebDriverInvoker.invoke(WebDriverInvoker.java:38)
... 41 more
```

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='container']/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/h3"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch your PageBase Class to below. You were earlier initializing the proxies but not returning that instance, just a new object. Else you can stick the initElements line in the constructor of CustomerHomePage using `'this'` instead of the `'CustomerHomePage.class'`

```
public class PageBase extends SeleniumBase {

public CustomerHomePage customerHomePage()
{
    return PageFactory.initElements(driver, CustomerHomePage.class);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Works as explained

Comment: what I don't really understand at this stage is why all the methods which now use the FindBy's bomb out with NoSuchElementExceptions.  When I debug with breakpoints, the test runs fine. So, there is a synchronisation issue with FindBy's.  Is it the case that the initElements tries to find the locators before the WebDriver has driven to the relevant page or page area?  As per the test, I am referencing several different PageObjects so some of the FindBy's may try to initialise before the Page has been loaded?

Comment: It does not matter where you initialize the PageObjects because PageFactory.initElements only provides proxies for the WebElement fields marked with @FindBy annotation. But when you access these fields, for methods such as sendkeys or click, you have to make sure the browser is on the correct page. You can compare the current URL with what you want for the PageObject or else have a look at LoadableComponent class. If you are getting NoSuchElementExceptions which disappear in debug mode then you need to use WebDriverWait and ExpectedConditions class to synchronize properly.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense.  I've updated the code with current implementation and details of where exception is being thrown. Not quite sure why my call to 'waitForIsDisplayed' is not being respected - it is the 'searchResults' locator that cannot be found but it is trying to find it before that page has loaded. SearchResultsPage is a seperate PageObject

Comment: Your PageBase class is not correct. You are returning the new instance rather than the one with the PageFactory.initElements call.

Comment: ...it just doesn't like this:  waitForIsDisplayed(searchResults, 120);   for some reason

Comment: In TestBase class you have the click function which is waiting before you have clicked the button. public void click(WebElement element) {
    waitForIsDisplayed(element, 120);
    element.click();
} Remove the waitisDisplayed from there.

Comment: Disregard previous comment.

Comment: I think this explains what I am seeing. Need to find a different Wait method: https://amitstechblog.wordpress.com/2011/07/24/java-proxies-and-undeclaredthrowableexception/

Comment: Is the locator for the searchResults element correct? Have you checked it in the browser manually? Does a Thread.sleep() work here instead of wait? Try with this condition visibilityOfElementLocated(By locator)?

Comment: The locator is good.  A Thread sleep does work. But, when I change the method (and selector) to use visibilityOfElementLocated(By locator), I get the same undesriable behaviour.  I can catch the UndeclaredThrowableException but for some reason the wait does not get respected so the Assertion always fails

Comment: I found out the issue was when I was creating a newproxyinstance of WebDriver. Once I removed that and used a more basic local instance = problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Variable name in your `@FindBy` is `drioDownLocator` and one you are passing is `dropDownContainer`. Is there any other variable too with `WebElement` type in your class ?